# How to ssh into a shell and run a script and leave myself at the prompt

Tags: shell, hadoop, amazon-web-services, ssh

I am using elastic map reduce from Amazon. I am sshing into hadoop master node and executing a script like.

`$EMR_BIN/elastic-mapreduce --jobflow $JOBFLOW --ssh  < hivescript.sh`  . It sshes me into the master node and runs the hive script. The hivescript contains the following lines

`hive
add jar joda-time-1.6.jar;
add jar EmrHiveUtils-1.2.jar;`

and some commands to create hive tables. The script runs fine and creates the hive tables and everything else, but comes back to the prompt from where I ran the script. How do I leave it sshed into hadoop master node at the hive prompt.

Comment: If you want to execute your script and stay on the machine, why don't you just `ssh` on your node, then run your script (instead of doing the same in one command) ?

Comment: I am automating this process , the parent script will be run by some end user, who should then be left at the hive prompt for executing some queries.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

These are the most common answers I've seen (with the drawbacks I ran into with them):

1. Use `expect`

   - This is probably the most well rounded solution for most people
   - I cannot control whether `expect` is installed in my target environments
   - Just to try this out anyway, I put together a simple `expect` script to ssh to a remote machine, send a simple command, and turn control over to the user.  There was a long delay before the prompt showed up, and after fiddling with it with little success I decided to move on for the time being.
   - Eventually I came back to this as the final solution after realizing I had violated one of the [3 virtues of a good programmer](http://threevirtues.com) -- false impatience.
2. Use `screen` / `tmux` to start the shell, then inject commands from an external process.

   - This works ok, but if the terminal window dies it leaves a `screen/tmux` instance hanging around.  I could certainly try to come up with a way to just re-attach to prior instances or kill them; `screen` (and probably `tmux`) can make it die instead of auto-detaching, but I didn't fiddle with it.
3. If using `gnome-terminal`, use its `-x` or `--command` flag (I'm guessing `xterm` and others have similar options)

   - I'll go into more detail on problems I had with this on #4
4. Make a bash script with `#!/bin/bash --init-file` as the shebang; this will cause your script to execute, then leave an interactive shell running afterward

   - This and #3 had issues with some programs that required user interaction before the shell is presented to them.  Some programs (like `ssh`) it worked fine with, others (`telnet`, `vxsim`) presented a prompt but no text was passed along to the program; only ctrl characters like `^C`.
5. Do something like this: `xterm -e 'commands; here; exec bash'`.  This will cause it to create an interactive shell after your commands execute.

   - This is fine as long as the user doesn't attempt to interrupt with `^C` before the last command executes.

Currently, the only thing I've found that gives me the behavior I need is to use `cmdtool` from the OpenWin project.

```
/usr/openwin/bin/cmdtool -I 'commands; here'
# or
/usr/openwin/bin/cmdtool -I 'commands; here' /bin/bash --norc
```

The resulting terminal injects the list of commands passed with `-I` to the program executed (no parms means default shell), so those commands show up in that shell's history.

What I don't like is that the terminal `cmdtool` provides feels so clunky ... but alas.

Answer (score 1):

Consider using Expect, then you could do something along these lines and `interact` at the end:

```
/usr/bin/expect <<EOF
spawn ssh ... YourHost
expect "password"
send "password\n"
send javastuff 
interact
EOF
```

Comment: I wrote this `/usr/bin/expect <<EOF
spawn $EMR_BIN/elastic-mapreduce --jobflow $JOBFLOW --ssh
expect "hivescript:"
send hivescript.sh
interact
EOF
`